# oracle stored procedure split string for insert or update to a table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Hi I apologize if my english is bad. I'm new in PL/SQL, and I have to make a stored procedure that receives a string separated values in this form:

```
device_id | table | operation_type | field_1 | field_2| field_n

device_id = Number of a device

table = Table Destiny

operation_type = "I" for insert "U" for update.

field_1 = a field value

field_2 = a field value

field_3 = a field value

field_4 = a field value
```

An example of the string could be like this:

```
"555;table_a;I;123;abc;xyz?456;def;uvw?...;...;...;"

; = value colums separator

? = row separator
```

For the string the first three values appears only once, the next ones values are the data for insert or update in the destiny table.

How can I take the string values and assemble the query (insert/update)?

```
table_a

field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_4

123     | abc     | xyz     | 555 

456     | def     | uvw     | 555
```

Thanks for your help, I would really appreciated it.

Comment: Use code tags for your code please.

Comment: Why did you choose such a convoluted way to pass parameters?

Comment: Hi, mustaccio, it's a requirement.

Comment: can you tell us which version of oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle 11 G Aramillo.

Comment: Wolf, Thank you for the edit, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create or replace procedure InsertUpdateValues(cad varchar2) is
data_v DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE;
table_name varchar2(75) := regexp_substr(cad,'[^;]+',instr(cad,';',1,1)); --get table name
operation varchar2(1) := regexp_substr(cad,'[^;]+',instr(cad,';',1,2)); --get operation
id number:=to_number(regexp_substr(cad,'[^;]+',1)); --get id (500) in this case 

begin
select regexp_substr(dat,'[^\?]+',1,level,'i') rows_data bulk collect into data_v  from 
(select regexp_substr(cad,'.*',instr(cad,';',1,3)+1) dat from 
dual)
connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (dat , '[^\?]+'))  +1;

for i in 1..data_v.count loop
    if lower(operation) = 'i' then
        execute immediate 'insert into '||table_name||' values (:f1,:f2,:f3,:f4)'
        using regexp_substr(data_v(i),'[^;]+',1,1),regexp_substr(data_v(i),'[^;]+',1,2),regexp_substr(data_v(i),'[^;]+',1,3),id;

    end if;
    if lower(operation) = 'u' then
        execute immediate 'update '||table_name||' set field_2 = :f2, field_3 = :f3 , field_4 = :f4 where field_1 = :f1' using
        regexp_substr(data_v(i),'[^;]+',1,2),regexp_substr(data_v(i),'[^;]+',1,3),id,regexp_substr(data_v(i),'[^;]+',1,1);

    end if;
end loop;

end;
```

And call it like this:

```
begin
InsertUpdateValues('555;table_a;I;123;abc;xyz?456;def;uvw');
end;
```

This inserts in table_a values :

```
field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_4

123     | abc     | xyz     | 555 

456     | def     | uvw     | 555
```

Comment: thanks, I'm having these problems with these block:  `select regexp_substr(dat,'[^\?]+',1,level,'i') rows_data bulk collect into data_v  from 
(select regexp_substr(cad,'.*',instr(cad,';',1,3)+1) dat from 
dual)
connect by level <= regexp_count(dat,'\?')+1;` The errors are: **Error(8,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored** and **Error(11,21): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "REGEXP_COUNT": invalid identifier** I'm using sqldeveloper.